# Swift: passing a C Function (SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack)

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I'm trying to call `SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback` the second parameter of which is `SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack`

In the Swiftified `SCNetworkReachability.h`, this is defined as:

`typealias SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack = CFunctionPointer<((SCNetworkReachability!, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void)>`

In Objective-C, I'd declare a function like:

```
static void MYReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info) {
    // do something
}
```

and pass this as a parameter. I'n Swift it seems that I should be passing a closure with the signature defined in `SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack`, something like this:

```
let callback = { (target: SCNetworkReachability!, flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) in
    // Do something
}
```

but this gives the error:

> Cannot convert the expression's type '(SCNetworkReachability!,
>   SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, UnsafeMutablePointer) ->
>   (SCNetworkReachability!, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer) -> $T0' to type '(SCNetworkReachability!,
>   SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, UnsafeMutablePointer) ->
>   (SCNetworkReachability!, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer) -> $T0'

which is somewhat puzzling!

Has anyone else come across this problem or has a solution?

Comment: This is currently not supported, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057161/how-to-use-the-coreaudio-api-in-swift for a similar issue. I think this restriction still applies to beta 7.

Answer (score -5):

```
static void MYReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info) {
        // do something
}
```

Comment: That's just the C callback from my question!